# are php files executed parallel or sequential?

Tags: php

If two users execute the same php file, will it be executed  parallel or sequential? Example:

If I have a database *data* which only has one column *id* would it be possible that the following code produces for two different users the same outcome?

```
1.  $db=startConnection();
2.  $query="SELECT id FROM data";
3.  $result=$db->query($query)or die($db->error);
4.  $zeile=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
5.  $number=$zeile['id'];
6.  $newnumber=$number+1;
7.  echo $number;
8.  $update = "UPDATE data Set id = '$newnumber'  WHERE id = '$number'";
9.  $db->query($query)or die($db->error);                       
10. mysqli_close($db);
```

If it is not executed parallel, does it mean when 100 people are loading a php file that has a loading time of 1 second, then one of them has to wait 99 seconds?

---

Edit: In the comments it is stated that I could messup my database, I guess this is how it could mess up:

User A executes the file from 1.-7. in this moment user B executes the file from 1.-7. then A loads 8.-10. and B loads 8.-10. In this scenario both users would have the same number on the screen.

Now lets take the following example:

```
1.  $db=startConnection();
2.  $query=" INSERT INTO data  VALUES ()";
3.  $result=$db->query($query)or die($db->error);
4.  echo $db->insert_id;                        
5.  mysqli_close($db);
```

Lets say A executes the file from 1.-3. in this moment user B executes the file from 1.-5., after that user A loads the file from 4.-5. I guess in this scenario also both would have the same number on the screen right? Does transaction prevent both scenarios?

Comment: Neither, each executes in its own independent thread; but that won't prevent your database access messing up.... that's why databases implement autoincrementing ids... if you try it yourself, there is a race condition risk, a database autoincrement eliminates that risk

Comment: That code may and will produce same outcome for different uses. To fix that, wrap your queries in a transaction

Comment: @MarkBaker Does this mean that if I call a insert query and then $db->insert_id I could get a id of a different insert query which has been excecuted in an other script?

Comment: `$db->insert_id` is guaranteed to work correctly and always return the right id without risk of duplication across any number of threads, the database handles this cleanly for autoincrement ids.... it's provided by the databases for exactly this purpose

Comment: @MarkBaker could you check my example in my edited post? Isn't that a case where also insert_id would fail?

Comment: @Nihat why did you delete your answer?

Comment: Why do you think it would fail? As long as you are using autoincrement ids and last_insert_id, the database __guarantees__ that it won't fail.... database manufacturers solved this problem many decades ago, it handles contention for ids to ensure that they are unique, it's tried and tested and works.... the only exceptions is if you're running truly distributed databases, when you use guids instead

Comment: @Adam even though my answer was fine (using transactions), I realized the better answer for this person would be to set the id to be auto_increment like suggested above so you wont face problems in other places.

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry I do not understand what you mean with it is guaranteed that it won't fail. How can you guarantee that no other insert query has happend during line 2. and 4. ?

Comment: @Adam Also, your query seems to be getting same id from data table. is it a one row table? Otherwise, it does not make sense what you are trying to do

Comment: I don't guarantee it.... MySQL guarantees it.... it handles that contention internally, and individual ids will be allocated to each individual thread... many developers complain that it can lead to "gaps"  in the sequence of ids, but that's your proof that it does work

Comment: I just undeleted my answer four your knowledge

Comment: maybe your id makes sense.. what is  it? is it showing number of users on site?

Comment: Sorry - I am very confused that the first example can produces for two different users the same outcome and second can't. I dont see the difference.

Comment: If you really don't trust the database to handle unique ids, then you have major problems.... but your own code isn't guaranteed to provide uniqueness when faced with multiple concurrent transactions because it will fail if using a non-transactional engine, or if the database implements any form of snapshotting

Comment: The database maintains an internal id for every autoincrement column, with mechanisms to handle contention when generating a new id so that every thread will increment then return the new value, even if this results in gaps in the sequence

Comment: Access to that internal autoincrement id is queued, only one process is able to access it at a time (though as it only takes nanoseconds to for each request to retrieve a new id it isn't a significant time overhead).... the database handles this all internally, and is a prerequisite for any relational database to provide this mechanism.... if a thread subsequently decides not to use the number it was allocated (e.g. rollback or similar) then that id won't be re-allocated, but simply leave a gap in the sequence

Comment: I deleted my answer because Dador's is much more comprehensive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can say that php files executed parallel (for most cases it is so, but this depends on web server).

Yes, it is possible that the following code produces for two different users the same outcome.

### How to avoid this possibility?

1) If you are using MySQL, you can use transactions **and** "SELECT ... UPDATE FOR" to avoid this possibility. Just using transaction wouldn't help!

2) Be sure that you are using InnoDB or any other database engine that support transactions. For example MyISAM **doesn't** support transactions. Also you can have problems if any form of snapshotting is enabled in the database to handle reading locked records.

3) Example of using "SELECT ... UPDATE FOR":

```
$db = startConnection();

// Start transaction
$db->query("START TRANSACTION") or die($db->error);

// Your SELECT request but with "FOR UPDATE" lock 
$query = "SELECT id FROM data FOR UPDATE";
$result = $db->query($query);


// Rollback changes if there is error
if (!$result)
{
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
    die($db->error);
}


$zeile = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$number = $zeile['id'];
$newnumber = $number + 1;
echo $number;

$update = "UPDATE data Set id = '$newnumber'  WHERE id = '$number'";
$result = $db->query($query);

// Rollback changes if there is error
if (!$result)
{
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
    die($db->error);
}    

// Commit changes in database after requests sucessfully executed
mysql_query("COMMIT");

mysqli_close($db);
```

### Why just using transaction wouldn't help?

Just transaction will lock only for write. You can test examples bellow by running two mysql console clients in two separate terminal windows. I did so and that's how it works.

We have client#1 and client#2 that executed parallel.

#### Example #1. Without "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE":

```
client#1: BEGIN
client#2: BEGIN
client#1: SELECT id FROM data // fetched id = 3
client#2: SELECT id FROM data // fetched id = 3
client#1: UPDATE data Set id = 4  WHERE id = 3
client#2: UPDATE data Set id = 4  WHERE id = 3
client#1: COMMIT
client#2: COMMIT
```

Both clients fetched the same id (3).

#### Example #2. With "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE":

```
client#1: BEGIN
client#2: BEGIN
client#1: SELECT id FROM data FOR UPDATE // fetched id = 3
client#2: SELECT id FROM data FOR UPDATE // here! client#2 will wait for end of transaction started by client#1
client#1: UPDATE data Set id = 4  WHERE id = 3
client#1: COMMIT
client#2: client#1 ended transaction and client#2 fetched id = 4
client#1: UPDATE data Set id = 5  WHERE id = 4
client#2: COMMIT
```

### Hey, I think such read-locks reduce performance!

"SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" do read-lock only for clients that use "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE". That's good, cause it means that such read-lock wouldn't affect on standart "SELECT" requests without "FOR UPDATE".

### Links

[MySQL documentation: "SELECT ... FOR UPDATE" and other read-locks](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

Comment: Just to avoid transaction issues with this it might be worth indicating that it won't work with non-transactional database engines such as MyISAM; and will still have problems if any form of snapshotting is enabled in the database to handle reading locked records

Comment: So the rollback is important because otherwise the table would be locked forever?

Answer (score 3):

### Parallel or Sequential?

Part of your question was about PHP running either parallel or sequential. As I have read everything and its opposite about that topic, I decided to test it myself.

**Field testing:**

On a LAMP stack running PHP 5.5 w/ Apache 2, I made a script with a very expensive loop:

```
function fibo($n)
{
    return ($n > 1) ? fibo($n - 1) + fibo($n - 2) : 1;
}

$start = microtime(true);
print "result: ".fibo(38);
$end = microtime(true);
print " - took ".round(($end - $start), 3).' s';
```

**Result with 1 script running:**

> result: 63245986 - took 19.871 s

**Result with 2 scripts running at the same time in two different browser windows:**

> result: 63245986 - took 20.753 s
>
> result: 63245986 - took 20.847 s

**Result with 3 scripts running at the same time in three different browser windows:**

> result: 63245986 - took 26.172 s
>
> result: 63245986 - took 28.302 s
>
> result: 63245986 - took 28.422 s

**CPU usage while running 2 instances of the script:**

[image]

**CPU usage while running 3 instances of the script:**

[image]

### So, it's parallel!

Althoug inside a PHP script, you can't easily use multithreading (while it's possible), Apache takes benefit from your servers having multiple cores to dispatch the load.

So if your 1-second script is run by 100 users at the same time, well if you have 100 CPU cores the 100th user will hardly notice anything. If you have 8 CPU cores (which is more common), then the 100th user will **theoritically** have to wait something like `100 / 8 = 12.5` seconds for his instance of the script to begin. In practice, as the "benchmark" puts in evidence, each thread's performance diminishes when other threads are running at the same time on other cores. So it could be a lot more. But not 100 seconds more.

Comment: This is great buddy, thank you. Also, check out this cool benchmarking script for future use! :) http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/241437-benchmarking/

Answer (score 0):

Depends. Usually php scripts are executed in parallel, but there are several things that can it make execute sequentially and thus dirty your tests:

1. most probably because browser, if you use same browser for tests, use two or more browsers, or even better a script calling to curl.
2. server configuration may sequentialize calls on certail url or from certain ip... check using your pc and handheld device for discarding.
3. some scripts may implement protections like locks, posix syncronizing methods (criticals, semaphores...) or db transactions to avoid certain critical parts be executed in parallel to avoid inconsistencies.

Best option is to test in your scenario: add an sleep or procesive-indensive-loop inside your script/critical region/protected code area/db transaction code and check. Remember using same and different urls/ips/browsers to get a better overall idea.